# Duration of Inventory Out of Stocks

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I posted the following question almost 2 years ago and received a perfect answer, but now I need to expand on the question to get Duration of Out of Stocks.  Here's the original question and answer I was provided:

"I need to determine patterns of inventory instock and out of stock.

I have a table that shows item, location, inventory and date. I want to see if there is a pattern to the times when an item/location is out of stock and instock over time. The file contains a rolling three weeks of data. If an item is consistently going instock or out of stock in three weeks, then I need to know about it to research further.

An item/location is instock if inventory greater than zero. An item/location is out of stock if inventory is zero or negative.

Thanks for any assistance.

Sample data

```
Item, location, inventory, date
1243, 10,       2,         3/12/2012
1243, 10,       0,         3/13/2012
1243, 10,      -2,         3/14/2012
1243, 10,      -2,         3/15/2012
1243, 10,       4,         3/16/2012
```

Then additional item, location, inventory, date records. "

I received this answer, which works perfectly.

```
SELECT item,
   location,
   SUM( CASE WHEN status = 'In Stock' AND prior_status = 'Out of Stock'
             THEN 1
             ELSE 0
         END) moved_to_out_of_stock,
   SUM( CASE WHEN status = 'Out of Stock' AND prior_status = 'In Stock'
             THEN 1
             ELSE 0 
          END) moved_to_in_stock
  FROM (SELECT item, 
           location,
           status,
           lag( status ) over (partition by item, location
                                   order by dt) prior_status
      FROM (SELECT item, 
                   location, 
                   (case when inventory <= 0 
                         then 'Out of Stock'
                         else 'In Stock'
                     end) status,
                   dt
              FROM your_table))
  GROUP BY item, location
```

Now I want to be able to determine the duration of the 'Out of Stock' each time it occurs.  Basically how many days was the item, location Out of Stock each time it was Out of Stock.

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT
Here's the query I currently use:

```
select ari.ITEM, x.LOCATION, MOVED_TO_OUT_OF_STOCK, MOVED_TO_IN_STOCK
from (select item, location, 
SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'In Stock' AND prior_status = 'Out of Stock'
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
             END)
moved_to_out_of_stock,
SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'Out of Stock' AND prior_status = 'In Stock'
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
             END)
moved_to_in_stock
  FROM (select item, location, status, lag(status)
  over (partition by item, location
  order by repl_date) prior_status
  FROM (select item, location,(CASE WHEN (stock_on_hand - demo_stock - non_sellable_qty) <='0'--subtract demo stock and non sellable qty
  then 'Out of Stock'
  else 'In Stock'
  end)
  status, repl_date
  from repl_results))
  group by item, location) x, active_repl_items ari,
  (select item, location, min(repl_date) as min_repl_date from repl_results
  group by item, location)y,
  (select item, location, repl_date, (STOCK_ON_HAND-DEMO_STOCK-NON_SELLABLE_QTY) AS  NET_AVAIL from repl_results) z
where (x.item = ari.item or x.item = ari.primary_pack_no) --to account for pack_items
and x.item = y.item and x.item = z.item
and x.location = y.location and x.location = z.location
and y.min_repl_date = z.repl_date
and x.location = ari.location
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach to your problem.  Add a 0/1 flag each time you find an out-of-stock condition.  Then do a cumulative sum of this flag.  This cumulative sum identifies out-of-stock conditions in sequence.  When you aggregate by this cumulative sum, you can get the duration of out of stock conditions:

```
select item, location, ooi_grp, min(dt) as mindt, max(dt) as maxdt,
       (max(dt) - min(dt) + 1) as duration
from (select t.*, sum(startooi_flag) over (partition by item, location order by dt) as ooi_grp
      FROM (SELECT item, location, status,
                   (case when lag(inventory) over (partition by item, location order by dt) > 0 and
                              inventory <= 0
                         then 1 else 0
                    end) as startooi_flag
            FROM your_table
           ) t
     ) t
where inventory <= 0
group by item, location;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Unfortunately, my SQL knowledge is much too small to be able to put your recommendation into my code.  I've added my current SQL code to the original question.  Would you be able to put your recommended code into the original?  Thanks and sorry to be a pain, but I do truly appreciate your help.